# How to make Area2D keep track of body entry all the time?

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

sorry for my bad english.
I have a problem. I need to make Area2D keep track of body entered all the time but it did it one time. How i can track this?

Code that i tried to use:

```
var hp = 10
var hero_in_me = false

func _physics_process(delta):
    if hero_in_me == true:
      hp -= 1
      print(hp)

func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body):
    if body.name == "Hero":
       hero_in_me = true
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "all the time", given that the `"body_entered"` signal notifies you when the body entered. So, either you want to know all the time the body is inside, or you want to register when the body *exited* and *entered* again.

Either way, you would, of course, need to handle when the body *exists* the `Area2D`, so you know when the body is no longer inside.

Assuming the `"body_entered"` signal is connected to `_on_Area2D_body_entered` and the `"body_exited"` signal is connected to `_on_Area2D_body_exited`, you could do this:

```
var hero_in_me = false

func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body):
    if body.name == "Hero":
       hero_in_me = true

func _on_Area2D_body_exited(body):
    if body.name == "Hero":
       hero_in_me = false
```

And there you can check for `hero_in_me`.

Or like this:

```
var hero = null

func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body):
    if hero == null and body.name == "Hero":
       hero = body

func _on_Area2D_body_exited(body):
    if body == hero
       hero = null
```

And there you can check for `hero != null`. And you also have the reference if you need to call into it.

Or if you want to keep track of all the bodies that enter the `Area2D`, you can store them in an array:

```
var bodies_inside := []

func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body):
    bodies_inside.append(body)

func _on_Area2D_body_exited(body):
    bodies_inside.erase(body)
```

Then to check if a particular body is inside, you could check `bodies_inside.has(body)`. You could also loop over the array to access all the bodies.